# Proving short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $M_k=\mathbb C[X]/\langle X^k\rangle$ $(k\ge 0)$. This is an $R$-module.

So far I have shown that there are for $0\le a\le b$ well-defined $R$-module homomorphisms $$u:M_a\rightarrow M_b\quad\text{and}\quad v:M_b\rightarrow M_{b-a}$$ with $u(X^n+\langle X^a\rangle)=X^{n+b-a}+\langle X^b\rangle$ and $v(X^n+\langle X^b\rangle)=X^n+\langle X^{b-a}\rangle$.

Now the exercise is:

> Show that for $0\le a\le b$ $$0\rightarrow M_a\overset{u}{\rightarrow}M_b\overset{v}{\rightarrow}M_{b-a}\rightarrow 0$$ is a short exact sequence.

I need help with all of the three things which I have to show, ie.

- $u$ is injective
- $v$ is surjective
- $\text{im}(u)=\text{ker}(v)$

Comment: I assume you meant to type $M_k=\Bbb C[X]/\langle X^k\rangle$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

$$X^{n+b-a}\in\langle X^b\rangle\iff n-a\ge0\iff n\ge a\iff \;X^n\in\langle X^a\rangle$$

and you already have injectivity of $\;u\;$ , and as surjectivity of $\;v\;$ is almost completely trivial, you're left only with Im$\,u=\ker v\;$, but also
$$\left(X^{n+b-a}+\langle X^b\rangle\right):= X^{n+b-a}+\langle X^{b-a}\rangle=0  \;\text{ (in the quotient}\;\;M_{b-a})$$

and you have already  Im $\,u\subset\ker v\;$ . Now you try what is left.

Comment: My problem is for example: elements of $\text{im}(u)$ are polynomials and they can have another form than $X^m$. So $X^{n+b-a}+<X^b>$ is not the general form of an element in the image.

Comment: @user114179 There are no polynomials in that short exact sequence but left cosets in quotient modules. And yes: that thing you wrote **is the general form** of an element in Im$\,u\;$

Comment: Yes but you know what I mean, don't you? There are no coefficients etc.

Comment: @user114179 No, I don't think I understand, and that "there are no coefficients" is something we don't care as **that** is the way **you** defined $\;u\;$ , so *there don't need to be* . I think you're missing the intention here: we **must** extend $\;u\;$ to the general elements in $\;M_a\;$ , for example: $$\;u(3X^2-1+\langle X^a\rangle):=3X^{2+b-a}-x^{b-a}+\langle X^b\rangle\;$$ , say.

Comment: $u$ is defined on $M_a$, so $u(2X+34X^3+<X^a>)$ is defined and in the image of $u$. You only consider Elements of the form $X^{n+b-a}+<X^b>$ being in the image.

Comment: @user114179 Read the whole comment.

Comment: Yeah, okay. But why is your calculation enough?

Comment: @user114179 Because...Seriously, my answer is for you to understand the general situation, and it shall be way more than enough for you to complete the solution.